# Mainframe monitoring using Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, mainframe

I've been working on setting up a monitoring solution for IBM Z mainframes using Zabbix. However, after conducting thorough searches, I haven't been able to find suitable agents or resources to link Zabbix with IBM Z mainframes.

If anyone has experience or knowledge in this area, could you please guide me on where to find the necessary agents or provide step-by-step instructions on integrating Zabbix with IBM Z mainframes?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be out of luck. The mainframe is a extremely mature platform and so are the tools that monitor it. There are in excess of 1,100 distinct metrics to monitor and so the model of "CPU/MEMORY/Disk space/ network" just doesn't work.

As such, there are a several established tools such as Sysview, Omagamon and others that run on the mainframe and have done so for decades.

Some of the open-source tools that do attempt to enable some form of mainframe monitoring do so by having the established mainframe tools send them 'events' and alerts rather than by trying to run on the mainframe and interface with the OS's monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your response! Currently, we're utilizing OMEGAMON, and I'm exploring the possibility of forwarding metrics from it to open-source tools like ELK stack or Prometheus with Grafana integration. I'm considering the use of ZOWE API for this purpose. However, I encounter a challenge in monitoring all LPARTs within the mainframe, and storage DASDs. I'm seeking the most effective solution to achieve this. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: This should be a comment.